# Is worth keeping the Linux distros tags here?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I believe that there are too many of them considering how badly they *usually* are used.

And in most of the cases you will think that the question (even when answered here) I believe most of them would fit better in [SuperUser][10] [Unix & Linux][11] or [AskUbuntu][12].

**Shouldn't we merge them into the Linux tag?** (or use as synonyms)

- [fedora10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedora10)
- [fedora11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedora11)
- [fedora12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedora12)
- [fedora16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedora16)
- [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu)
- [redhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redhat)
- [archlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archlinux)
- [slackware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slackware)
- [linuxmint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linuxmint)

PS: comment/edit if you think I missed one distro.

Comment: I'd be inclined to err on the side of *there are still valid uses for each individual flag* but now that there are entire SE sites for a lot of these individually, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Sometimes these are as bad as company tags... but sometimes they're valuable.  For example, `apache2` + `ubuntu` may likely be *hugely* different from `apache2` + `redhat` because of the radically different ways each distribution does configuration.  They're worth keeping.  Barely.

Comment: They don't seem useful as tags - as the search results show, they attract a wide variety of totally unrelated questions. Not every concept needs to be tagged - question-askers can still mention relevant details like OS/release in the text of their question.

Comment: @Charles, even your example most question that could be made on an e.g. **Apache + distro** would still have a lot of tendency to be a question for ServerFault.com (as you said about configuration). And I agree with **Andrew Medico**, you can always tell all the relevant details.